# Proceed to Checkout button directing to homepage instead of next step in magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento, checkout, magento-1.9.1

So the problem is when i upload the website to live server. Everything works fine in local environment.

When i click the Proceed to checkout button it redirects me to the homepage. this does not happen in local environment.

In the live server I have Flushed magento cache; flushed web hosting account cache; Enable error logging but there are no errors, also no extensions are installed.

Comment: What have you done to debug the code?

Comment: try to clear `log_url` and its related tables.

Answer (score 0):

What does the link for proceed to checkout say in inspector? What i will usually do to troubleshoot issues as such is enabling the default theme to see if the issue still occurs. If it doesn't then it's theme specific. From there, run red lines with the theme having the problem and verify the block with the proceed to cart button doesn't have an error by comparing it to the base theme block.

Comment: I think you should use comments for this not as answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.looogo-web.com/web-design-company-blog/proceed-to-checkout-button-goes-back-to-home-page-empty-cart-magento-cart-issue/

Changing these settings from the admin panel solved my problem.